# MYSQL Сортировка записей при выборке

Tags: mysql

Имеем структуру таблицы:

```
menuID  |  parentID  |  arrange  |  title
--------|------------|-----------|--------------
 1      |  NULL      |  20       |  root menu 2
 2      |  NULL      |  10       |  root menu 1
 3      |  2         |  NULL     |  subroot 1.1
 4      |  2         |  NULL     |  subroot 1.2
 5      |  2         |  NULL     |  subroot 1.3
```

При выборке нужно расположить строки так, чтоб сначала отсортировать по значениям `arrange` корневых пунктов меню, а потом "вложенных":

```
menuID  |  parentID  |  arrange  |  title
--------|------------|-----------|--------------
 2      |  NULL      |  10       |  root menu 1
 3      |  2         |  NULL     |  subroot 1.1
 4      |  2         |  NULL     |  subroot 1.2
 5      |  2         |  NULL     |  subroot 1.3
 1      |  NULL      |  20       |  root menu 2
```

Не могу сообразить, как составить запрос, чтобы записи с parentID = 2 шли после menuID = 2, с остальным вопросов не возникает.

Comment: делать на mysql этого не стоит, лучше собирать данные на клиенте. Если очень уж хочется - джойните таблицу второй раз по parentID и заполняете данные, которые равны null, значениями родительской записи из первой таблицы. Таким образом приведете записи таблицы к одному виду и проблем уже не возникнет

Comment: И если уровней вложенности меню больше 1 то посмотрите в гугле по "mysql connect by", там приводятся разные способы получения нужного вам эффекта. правда они все очень громоздкие

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно попробовать в подзапросе определить у дочерних записей `arrange` такой же как и у родительской записи, а потом отсортировать по нему и, например, `menuID`:

```
select menuID, parentID, arrange, title 
from
(
  select 
    menuID, parentID, arrange, title, 
    @arrange := if(parentID, @arrange, arrange) arrange2
  from 
  (
    select menuID, parentID, arrange, title
    from t
    order by ifnull(parentID, menuID)
  ) t, (select @arrange) q
) q
order by arrange2, menuID
```

[Sql Fiddle пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/51bdce/3)

Answer (score 1):

Когда-то собирал в одну методичку типовые подходы к хранению иерархий в БД
http://www.study.urfu.ru/Aid/Publication/9524/1/Prisyagnuy.pdf
кратенький обзор с примерами запросов с 27 страницы